# KVO conditionally fire method in observeValueForKeyPath

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

I have a countdown that counts down from 5. I use `KVO` on a float property that represents the countdown. It fires `observeValueForKeyPath` once or not at all. I want it fire `observeValueForKeyPath` until the property being observed matches a particular value, so it can fire a method in `observeValueForKeyPath`.

Please see code

EDIT

```
 __block float progress;
    self.countdown.labelVCBlock = ^(KAProgressLabel *label) {
        progress = 5-(label.progress *5);
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", (progress)];


    };

     self.progressFloat = 5.0f; //setting the initial value
     [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"progressFloat" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    self.progressFloat -= progress;//progress is a float that counts down from 5

}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"progressFloat"]) {
          NSLog(@"KVO called");
        if (self.progressFloat < 0.1f) {//when self.progressFloat is less than 0.1 second, then fire the method below. 

            [self takePhoto:nil];
        }
        }
    }
```

The method either fires immediately or `observeValueForKeyPath` never gets called.

Comment: The code you posted only shows `self.progressFloat` being changed once.  How does the count down happen?

Comment: @PhillipMills see edit

Comment: Just create a delegate.

Comment: Not sure what I'm supposed to see in the edit...`self.progressFloat` is still only being changed once after the observer is set.

Comment: The block updates `progress` which is subtracted for `self.progressFloat`

Comment: And where is that block being called?

Comment: You don't show where it's being subtracted unless you mean that you're repeatedly calling the method that sets `self.progressFloat` to 5 and adds the observer.

Comment: @PhillipMills no, the block runs over and over again, updating progress. But I get what you mean. `self.progressFloat` only gets updated once. @vienvu's answer below gets to the heart of it but I can't get it to work quite yet. Thanks for pointing that out, I got lost in the block.

Comment: Side note: if you notice yourself adding an object as an observer to itself (e.g, `self` observing a property on `self` as you have it), then you could just override the setter for the property

Comment: @AO Dude, awesome, I never thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you don't update your variable `progressFloat` in block. Try change code to:

```
__unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.countdown.labelVCBlock = ^(KAProgressLabel *label) {
    progress = 5-(label.progress *5);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", (progress)];
    weakSelf.progressFloat -= progress;
};
```

Comment: I've never seen weakSelf before, I'll give it a try

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs It just protect not retain cycle when using block.

Comment: I tried it but got red error. DO I have to declare it as weak instead of strong in the .h file?

Comment: weakSelf - sorry first time I saw that. I got the `weakSelf` working but it just freezes on the start of the block now. Hmmm...

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs what about free? App free UI?

Comment: @vien_vu I got it, had to remove observer. Thanks!